# script to add user and then show message if it was created or not

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I need to create a script that asks me the name of the user using adduser, and then show a message if was created or not

I tried with this but is not working

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter username"
read user
useradd $user
if `cat /etc/passwd | grep $user`
then 
        echo "User created"
else
        echo "User not created :("
fi
```

Comment: What's not working?  Does it error out?  Does it ignore the input?  You need to provide more than "It's not working"

Comment: Note `adduser` is generally just a symlink to the actual Linux command `useradd`. I would encourage you to learn the actual commands as not all distributions provide the verb-first symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter username"
read user
if useradd $user
then
    echo "User created"
else
    echo "Not created"
fi
```

Comment: Or the equivalent `useradd $user && echo "User created" || echo "Not created"`  Your solution is fine, but you should never simply include `"Try this:"` as the sole explanation for your answer. (1) `"Try this"` intimates that you are unsure if your solution will work and the user should just try and see; (2) it does nothing to explain why what the user was doing was wrong, and how what you propose fixes it. A short explanation about using the return value to indicate success/failure would be appropriate. (no dings, just helpful suggestions)

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I wasn't 100% sure what was not working with his script, so I wasn't sure if this would fill in those gaps or not.

Comment: Yes, it was a quirky question, but right of the bat we have the `\`cat /etc/passwd | grep $user\`` *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of* `cat`). That shows a clear misunderstanding of the proper way to determine success/failure of the `useradd` command. You don't `cat` the `passwd` file and pipe it to `grep` to determine if `useradd` worked, you test the return value of the `useradd` command itself. Just background like that explains what he did wrong and what he needs to do to fix it -- that all dovetails nicely with the example you provide. You are free to use verbatim - then an UV is warranted.